# create aqua style buttons using php

Tags: php, gd, imagemagick

is it possible to create an image like this one using php with the help of GD/ImageMagick?

This image was generated by Web Button Maker Delux, which is a .NET App. So i think, may be there is an way for me to generate one using PHP.

So any help on that please?

Thanks,
Anjan

** in case image is broken here is another url of the sample image: http://www.ultrasoftbd.com/aqua.png

[image]

Comment: There is even a way to incorporate OpenGL in PHP and write a 3D shooter. You have to be more specific to get a good answer.

Comment: It is possible. Do you know how to make an image with php and ImageMagick?

Comment: @Vlad - My current problem at hand is -

1) Create a gradient image of rectanguler or rounder rectanguler shape with specified image
2) Then apply a "Glassy" effect on it (pardon me if the term is wrong)
3) Finally to add text centered to that image

Then save this image as transparent png.

@JoshD - I am familiar with GD, but with ImageMagic i m not much familiar with. Its not that i am Master on GD :D But i m more familier with GD than ImageMagick!

Comment: Isn't it easier to create three base images in Photoshop or whatever: left, middle, right. Then take the middle part using GD, put text on it (tons of tutorials on that) and stick the left and right part on there and you're done.

Comment: @Alec - Yes it would be easier, but then again i will have to provide option for any color gradient, which i think can't be provided manually using photoshop

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old post, but in the event that someone stumbles on this as I did, I have a solution.  I wrote a script for dynamically creating web buttons.  The script does essentially what Alec described, but is highly configurable and has more features.  I have used this script for a few years now and it works awesome.  It is also easy to change the look and feel of the buttons with a change of a few base images and you have a new button look across your entire site with very little effort.

I wrote a small article that breaks down the entire script and how to use it.  http://www.phpwebscripting.com/index.php?mact=Articles,cntnt01,details,0&cntnt01documentid=1&cntnt01returnid=69 I hope that people will find this useful.  I am releasing it as free software.  There is a link to download the script at the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial:

- http://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/php/php-gd-library.htm
- http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/dynamic_image_generation.php

These should guide you down the right path on using the GD library to create dynamic images